# How to extract data from a simple API Response?

Tags: php, api

I received an api response from the endpoint:

http://rest.sharethis.com/reach/getUrlInfo.php?url='http://www.mydomain.com/'

```
{ "email" : { "inbound" : 47498,
      "outbound" : "27459"
    },
  "facebook" : { "inbound" : 6311,
      "outbound" : "2301"
    },
  "other" : { "inbound" : 2196,
      "outbound" : "1456"
    },
  "sharethis" : { "inbound" : 16536,
      "outbound" : "7746"
    },
  "total" : { "inbound" : 80399,
      "outbound" : "40956"
    },
  "twitter" : { "inbound" : 4946,
      "outbound" : "1298"
    }
}
```

How can i get the sum of 'inbound + outbound' of the "total" variable into a string like $total for echoing out in php.

Comment: No offense, but if you cannot find out how to parse JSON with PHP and how to access an object graph, then you shouldnt be working with a REST API but get to grips with the basics first.

Comment: well i had to start learning some day and i did not know that it was JSON. I am still learning php.

Comment: Well, "start learning" is fine, just maybe start learning the basics instead ;)

Comment: yes sir. Actually i just wanted a small output with this JSON code. Otherwise i never touch apis and JSON. I mostly do HTML and CSS designs but recently getting into PHP. Can you suggest a way to quickly learn PHP.

Comment: I always suggest to read the [Language Reference in the PHP Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) to get an idea of how the language works. And then probably use a few tutorials from SitePoint.com and maybe buy a decent book. That might not be the fastest and easiest path given that there is also some advanced topics in the reference, but at least it might teach you some know-why instead of just some know-how.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, sir and i will follow it. However for the time being, can you help me with my question. I just want to call the API into a string and parse it like @gmadd described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$decoded = json_decode($string);
$inbound = $decoded->total->inbound;
$outbound = $decoded->total->outbound;
echo "Total: ".($inbound+$outbound);
```

Comment: this is the php. How should i call the api response before adding this php. Sorry, i am very new to coding.

Comment: @sam, what is the code that you are using to get the response above? Or is that what you're asking for? Not a problem :-)

Comment: i just have the url with me. how to get the JSON into a string (probably using cURL or get_contents) and then parse it as described by you.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to register to get an API key: 
http://help.sharethis.com/api/api-overview
Then read http://help.sharethis.com/api/urlinfo-api
You might be able to use something like:
$returnedData = file_get_contents(); using http://rest.sharethis.com/reach/getUrlInfo.php?url=&pub_key=&access_key=
with filling in the blanks, but someone might have a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be [JSON](http://www.json.org/).  You should check out [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which will turn your string into a PHP array that can be easily manipulated in the standard ways.