# extract specific data from a API response

Tags: python-2.7

to preface this i am a network engineer trying to dabble is software so excuse any simple questions - Hi, i am trying to extract a specific data field from an api call. Here is an example of a response in json, the field i want to extract is "dstprefix" along with prefix.

```
>>> print(response.json)
[{u'dstprefix': u'166.70.0.0/16', u'bits': 744091635, u'split1': {u'start': u'2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', u'end': u'2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', u'type': u'TIME_RANGE'}}, {u'dstprefix': u'67.2.0.0/16', u'bits': 478661859, u'split1': {u'start': u'2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', u'end': u'2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', u'type': u'TIME_RANGE'}},
```

here is the full code excluding the print line, is there a specific type of module i should be looking into to extract this data? Interested in digging into the details, not getting the answer, i just need some guidance as i've hit a wall

```
import requests, simplejson

url = "<private>"

querystring = {
  "hosts": [
    "<private>"
  ],
  "interval": "1m",
  "query": "SELECT sum(bps) as bits, dstprefix FROM raw_flows WHERE pop = 'slc01' AND ifrole_out REGEXP '^(PEER|ISP)' AND '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z' <= __time AND __time < '2023-09-28T18:13:00.000Z' GROUP BY dstprefix,TIME_BUCKET(__time, PT1M, 'Etc/UTC')  ORDER BY bits DESC LIMIT 100"
}

d = simplejson.dumps(querystring)
print(d)
response = requests.post(url, data=d)
```

some additional output, not sure if this is helpful

```
>>> print(type(response))
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
>>> print(str(response))
<Response [200]>
```

appreciate any feedback!

i have googled similar subjects as mine to attempt their fixes but none have worked thus far [trying to get specific data from API response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949001/trying-to-get-specific-data-from-api-response)
[How to extract data from a simple API Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578135/how-to-extract-data-from-a-simple-api-response)

when going with the json.loads() method i get the following error

```
>>> ntop = json.loads(response)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

so i attempt to turn this into a string and end up down a rabbit hole.

Comment: what's the output of `response.json()`?

Comment: @PaulH >>> response.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: figured out the fix .... for i in range(10):
 print(response.json[i]['dstprefix'])